# Looking for an alternative to the WaitForInputIdle function, available at any time

Tags: winapi

I'm working on an automation program, and the `WaitForInputIdle` function helps me determine when the window of the target app is done initializing. The problem is that, in my case, it works only with the first window - that's how `WaitForInputIdle` works, only once.

Could the functionality of `WaitForInputIdle` be implemented in a different way, such that it could be called every time the target process is busy, and wait until it's done?

I thought about posting a dummy message, but I don't think there's a way to find out when it gets removed from the queue.

Edit: I came up with something, an ugly and hacky solution that seems to work:

```
RECT rc;

if(!GetUpdateRect(hWnd, &rc, FALSE))
{
    rc.left = rc.top = 0;
    rc.right = rc.bottom = 1;
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rc, FALSE);
}

do {
    Sleep(100);
} while(GetUpdateRect(hWnd, &rc, FALSE));
```

I really hope there's something better than that.

Comment: Send the window a WM_NULL message.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, that worked for my case. In fact, I thought about using WM_NULL, but I assumed it wouldn't work because a sent message can be processed in various unintended scenarios, e.g. `TrackPopupMenu`, `SendMessage` and probably other functions I'm not aware of.

Comment: It works as well as your `PrintWindow` method, which sends a `WM_PAINT` message. (`WM_PAINT` is mostly posted, but it is sent if somebody is waiting for the result, like you are.)

Comment: "I thought about posting a dummy message, but I don't think there's a way to find out when it gets removed from the queue." - You can use a WH_GETMESSAGE hook for that. You can use GetWindowThreadProcessId() to limit the hook to just the thread that owns the window you are posting to.

Comment: WH_XXX hooks involve DLL injection, and that's too heavyweight for my needs. In fact, I've stumbled upon `WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE`, which might be exactly what I need, but it doesn't fit for the same reason. For now I'm using the `WM_NULL` method, and for specific apps - the `GetUpdateRect` method.

Comment: No hacks required. Just set up a [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) hook, and get notified whenever a window has been successfully created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit:* sending `WM_NULL`, as suggested by **Raymond Chen**, works for me.

It appears that the `PrintWindow` hack has no advantages, as internally it just sends the `WM_PAINT` message.

*Old message:* I came up with a solution that solves my problem, still a hack but not as ugly.

The idea is misusing the `PrintWindow` function, which basically <strike>posts</strike> sends a WM_PAINT message and waits for the window to process it - exactly what I need.
Below is the code with some informative comments.

It was tested on Windows XP and Windows 8 and it works as expected, i.e. doesn't fail despite the NULL HDC value.

```
// BEWARE: HACK BELOW
// PrintWindow is misused here as a synchronization tool
// When calling it, the system sends WM_PAINT and waits for it to be processed
// Note: if hWnd is hung, the following call will hang as well
PrintWindow(hWnd, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: This is a *very* elaborate way to use SendMessage instead of PostMessage.  Otherwise a good way to crash a program.

Comment: Well, use SendMessage instead.  Send something innocent, like WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, to minimize the possible side effects.  None of this actually provides a guarantee, you don't know what the program does *after* it responded.

Comment: The comment is incorrect. `PrintWindow` does not post `WM_PAINT`. It sends it.

Comment: I assumed it was posted because a) `WM_PAINT` is not usually sent, and b) `PrintWindow` is implemented in ring0, so I assumed it uses some kind of dark magic.

Wine actually just sends a message, though: http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/user32/painting.c#L1699