# WaitForInputIdle alternative approach

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, mfc, atl

I'm trying to open application using `ShellExecuteEx` and wait for it using `WaitForInputIdle`, this does work for some applications, but for some, i.e. `iexplorer.exe` it does not. `WaitForInputIdle` returns instantly. I understand it does not work as intended

```
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO shellExecuteInfo;
    shellExecuteInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    shellExecuteInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    shellExecuteInfo.hwnd = NULL;
    shellExecuteInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
    shellExecuteInfo.lpFile = reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(app->applicationFile.utf16());
    shellExecuteInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
    shellExecuteInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
    shellExecuteInfo.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    shellExecuteInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

    if(!ShellExecuteEx(&shellExecuteInfo)) {
        log(QString("Can not start application %1 with path %2. Last error is %3")
                                  .arg(app->buttonName)
                                  .arg(app->applicationFile)
                                  .arg(GetLastError()));

        return ProcessWindowsInfo();
    }

    //Waiting for 30 seconds
    DWORD result = WaitForInputIdle(shellExecuteInfo.hProcess, 30 * 1000);

    if(result != 0) {
        //report error and return
        return ProcessWindowsInfo();
    }

    ProcessWindowsInfo info(GetProcessId(shellExecuteInfo.hProcess));

    if(!findWindows(info)) {
        return info;
    }

    if(info.windows.empty()) {
        log(QString("Can not find windows for %1 with path %2")
                                  .arg(app->buttonName)
                                  .arg(app->applicationFile));

        return info;
    }

    resizeWindows(app, info);
    showWindows(app, info.windows);

    return info;
}
```

I saw other questions in StackOverflow that had the same issues like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405201/waitforinputidle-doesnt-work-for-starting-mspaint-programmatically).

I'm not a win32 developer so its difficult to see how to fix this with CBT hook or WinEvents as the previous post suggests. 
if Someone can point out the best approach to solve this issue.

There is also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247346/looking-for-an-alternative-to-the-waitforinputidle-function-available-at-any-ti), but again how do I get the handle for the application I just started?

Also, should I use `ShellExecuteEx` or `CreateProcess` and would that affect the ability to find the opened application?

Comment: What do you mean by "wait for it"? Would you like to wait until the process ends?

Comment: *`WaitForInputIdle` returns instantly.* - but it not return error ? *I understand it does not work as intended* - and how indented ? where and which error you get ? may be process, which you exec - just exit. in this case `WaitForInputIdle` returns instantly. with no error

Comment: The fact that you aren't experienced enough to implement the ideas described in the duplicate does not make this any less of a duplicate. That you don't know how to solve the problem using those ideas doesn't mean that there are other solutions that will be more suited to your current experience levels. The way forward is simple enough. Learn what you need to in order to solve the problem the right way.